# In angular.js, what does an ampersand in the directive mean?

Tags: angularjs

In this code:

```
app.directive( 'myCustomDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { value: '=myCustomDirective', clickable: '&', editing: '=' },
    template: '<span ng-click="handleClick()" ng-bind="value"></span>',
    ...
```

What does `clickable: '&'` denote?

When I do find Angular documentation, I cannot understand it.  It seems to be written in a catch-22 code that can be understood only by  people who already understand what is being explained.

For example, I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZGgNPTHc2Q), which apparently explains the & thing, but  he may as well have been speaking Mandarin.

Comment: I'm with you on the API documentation. It's about as helpful as MSDN (read: not very helpful) if you're a beginner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** The new directive API is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api)

There is some more explanations on the [Understanding Scopes doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#-directives), and they provide this useful [link](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/).

When I wanted to understand this stuff, I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/SbrKj/).

```
angular.module('scopePropertiesModule', [])
  .directive('scopeProps', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      scope: {parameterTitle:'@', 
              bidirecTitle:'=',
              delegateDisplay:'&'},
      template: '<div>' +
                  'Parameter title :<br>' + 
                  '<input ng-model="parameterTitle"> => {{parameterTitle}}<br>'+
                  '<br>' +
                  'Biderectional title :<br>' +
                  '<input ng-model="bidirecTitle"> => {{bidirecTitle}}<br>' + 
                  '<br>' +
                  'Delegate display :<br>' +
                  '{{delegateDisplay()}}<br>' + 
                  '</div>'  
    }
});
```

and the markup:

```
<div class="scopeProps"
     parameter-title="{{title}}" 
     bidirec-title="title"
     delegate-display="displayTitle()"></div>
```

Feel free to play with it.

Comment: the understanding scopes doc is very hard to understand

Comment: They should write an "Understanding 'Understanding Scopes'" guide

Comment: It would be better if you explicitly put the answer in the answer. The way it is now the answer reads something like this:  *"The answer is that if you use these links or if you study my code block maybe you can figure out the answer for yourself, but I'm not going to tell you"*

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (quick search for "scope")

From the docs:

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

Answer (score 7):

It means that when referring to the *clickable* variable in the directive scope, Angular evaluates the associated expression in the parent scope and assigns the result to the variable.
For example, if you include the directive in your HTML code this way:

```
<my-custom-directive ... clickable='initialized && i > 0' ...>
```

Angular will calculate the `initialized && i > 0` expression in the context of the page controller scope and assign the result to the clickable variable in the directive scope.
This will be done dynamically, the directive variable is updated every time the expression value changes.

Comment: I'm not sure the directive variable is automatically updated; the "directive variable" is a function that you have to call explicitly in order to evaluate that expression.